# New profile page: grey frame around profile image

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design, profile-page, profile-picture

First off, kudos for the [new profile page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/). I love it.

One thing though... the user image has this grey frame around its top half:

[image]

(I see this in three different browsers)

Is this intended? To me it gives the page somewhat an "under construction" look, like one part was forgotten in the style. Would an all-white background look better?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.

The designer wanted to break up the background a bit and make it a bit more interesting.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has the desired effect. When I first saw it I thought I had to upload a larger image file. It just doesn't look right. The image is floating in what looks like some left over space. It leaves a strong impression of some sizing issue. Which is sad, because for the rest the page looks extremely well-styled.